# Is there a square brand logo for use with OneDrive sign in?

Tags: onedrive, live-sdk

I'm using the Live/OneDrive API to do sign in using OAuth2. Is there a square icon (similar to those available for [Facebook](https://www.facebookbrand.com/) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines)) that Microsoft permit using?

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript, you can use `WL.ui` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550847.aspx)) with "signin" for the `name` parameter to generate a sign-in button. You can find some sample code and more information about signing in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659751.aspx

```html
<div id="signin"></div>
       
<script>
  WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
  WL.init({
    client_id: APP_CLIENT_ID,
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL,
    scope: "wl.signin",
    response_type: "token"
  });
  
  WL.ui({
    name: "signin",
    element: "signin"
  });
  
  function onLogin (session) {
    if (!session.error) {
      // Successful sign-in, do something
    }
    else {
      // Handle sign-in error
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too, however, I'm not using the JavaScript API, but vanilla OAuth2.